Compiling without a standard library but with the _start label (entry point)
I am building my own 32-bit x86 OS in which I load user programs from ELF files. When compiling the user C programs I use -nostdlib to exclude GLIBC and link my own LIBC instead. The problem is that by doing so, the program compiles without a _start label, causing the entry (defined in the ELF header) to point at the first piece of code in the file and not the actual entry of the program.
I am not sure how can I compile without the standard library but still have a valid entry point for the program.
When compiling with the -nostdlib flag I get:
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000

ELF file:
  Entry point address:               0x8049000

How can _start be generated with no stdlib?
Should and can I write it myself and link it at compile time with the user program?

Add your own _start function? You need to do that anyway, to set up the stack and BSS segments and other things  before you jump to the main function (which could be called anything you want). You could also modify the linker script to use any symbol you want, instead of _start. I suggest you take a look around the OSDev wiki, it has all the information you need to create your own OS kernel.

@Someprogrammerdude My kernel is near complete; I am asking how could I compile a user C program to be run on my kernel without the stdlib and still have the _start label.

The answer is basically the same: You need a _start function, which sets up stack, BSS, standard file handles, etc., and which then calls main. There's really nothing special about _start, it's a simple plain function almost like any other. I think the OSDEv wiki have information about that as well.

There are also --entry=ENTRY / -e ENTRY options that let you specify your own entry point.

What do you mean by "a user C program to be run on my kernel"?  Ordinarily, I would take "user program" to mean one running on top of your OS, in what C would call a "hosted" environment.  In such an environment, it is the responsibility of the C standard library (whether your own custom one or some other) to mediate programs' requests for kernel services.  Such a program does not run "on the kernel".  It runs on the provided, hosted, C implementation, including its C standard library.  Which makes that standard library a fine place for _start() or a similar function.

@JohnBollinger Oh I see, I only now realized that the _start function is part of the stdlib and not part of the compilation process. So you say that I should implement my own _start function in my libc and set the entry to it when linking?

My confusion was driven from the source of the _start function. Apparently, the _start function is part of the standard library, located in the crt0.S file.

crt0 (also known as c0) is a set of execution startup routines linked into a C program that performs any initialization work required before calling the program's main function.

When compiled with the -nostdlib flag, GCC removes GLIBC from the program together with its _start routine - causing the linker to raise an error telling it couldn't find a symbol to set the entry to.
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000
I fixed this by creating my own crt0.S file in my libc and in it a custom _start function to be linked with the user program.
So to my questions I would answer:

How can _start be generated with no stdlib? Should and can I write it myself and link it at compile time with the user program?

You should supply your own definition of the _start function in the standard library of your OS and link it with the user program.
